# How can I mock wxPython in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, wxpython, python-sphinx

I've made a project using wx-python v4.0.0b2 (Phoenix) and I'm trying to document it by using Sphinx now.

I have a directory structure as follow:

```
app/
 |----models/
 |       |----__init__.py
 |       |----foo.py
 |----views/
 |       |----__init__.py
 |       |----package1/
 |----__init__.py
docs/
 |----conf.py (normally this one is not considered at build) 
 |----rst/ (sphinx build src directory) 
 |      |----conf.py (this one has the mocks and imports) 
 [SHPINX project structure]
requirements.txt
[other stuff]
```

The fact is that, when I run `sphinx-build`, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alastard/dev/LowVoltageTool-final/docs/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 658, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/alastard/dev/LowVoltageTool-final/app/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import models, serialization, wxviews
  File "/home/alastard/dev/LowVoltageTool-final/app/wxviews/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import core, drawers, items, panels, patterns
  File "/home/alastard/dev/LowVoltageTool-final/app/wxviews/core/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named 'wx'
```

So I guess that the error comes from a problem in my conf.py, which contains the following:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
autodoc_mock_imports = ['anytree', 'numpy', 'scipy', 'wxPython']
```

So I'm really wondering how can I mock wxPython? And if not, how can I make sphinx work without doing so?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add `'wx'` to `autodoc_mock_imports`?

Comment: Damn, I feel like an idiot now. I was sure I've already done it. Well it worked now, thanks! Maybe can you write it as an answer so I can mark the question as resolved ;-)

Comment: Been there, done that, left the question in place for others to learn from whilst desperately wishing to delete it. Welcome to the club :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `'wx'` to the [`autodoc_mock_imports`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports) list.

`wx` is the package to be mocked. `wxPython` is the project, not the name of a package or module.